# how to send html with additional metadata so JS (ajax) knows what to do with response?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, metadata

I'm making requests with AJAX only, most of my requests returns html which i load to div#content (not only, bu let say its the most common action). Problem occurs when I have to send something like error message, for example when user session expired - then i have to 'clear user desktop' (replace whole body, not only #content). Ajax loading func, don't know what it will get, so server has to send some additional information, what to do with its response.

I thought about custom header, but wanted to know if there are some other possibilities or 'best practices' for this problem.

Comment: Something more than just [HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)?

Comment: Yes, something more, for example when, server wants to redraw other part of page than #content. But status codes ( + something custom for expired session) seems to be best approach for error handling.

Comment: and why nobody loves my custom header idea? ;]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send back more than just a HTML fragment to put in `#content`, but instead a fragment of JavaScript to be executed instead, or else a JSON document with a key to describe how to interpret it.

Comment: But it would require to traverse response before putting it into dom, are there any performance drawbacks with this method?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

- You could use the `<meta>` html tags to describe the problems.
- You could also simply send a hidden `<div>` or `<span>` or whatever
  and have it removed from the result on the AJAX receiving side.

Comment: i would prefer something where i dont need to traverse returned html.

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading in content with the possiblity of metadata attached, you probably want to be sending back JSON instead. Though it looks sloppy, it works well and is much easier to extract data from.

```
{"body": "<h1>I'm a title!</h1>", "errors": []}

{"body": "<h3>Session Expired</h3>", "errors": ["sessionExpired"]}
```

You can combine that with HTTP status codes, such as "422" which will kick off the error callback to further customize and specialize your code.

To check if you have any errors without status codes, all you have to do is ask for response.errors.length and see if it's, for example, 0.. in which case you know there were no errors. Otherwise you've got an an array of errors that have happened and you can loop through them to take care of those issues. To get the body out, just do $(response.body) - you now have a jquery-ized chunk of html that can be inserted anywhere.

Comment: I thought about it, but it would force me to change the way i'm returning page (which is jsp backed by Spring MVC). And it is something I don't want to do:/

Comment: About status codes - can i use custom status codes? It could be sufficient.

Comment: You could. Anything besides a 200 type code jquery interprets as an error.. so sending back 4XX codes with something containing the response would go through whatever callback you put in error slot. So, yeah, that could work. Just be careful to use the right codes.

Comment: Yeah, it could be enough for custom error handling. But there is still problem with other data, like, when page needs to replace whole body, not only main content. For such cases, i suppose sending metadata with an extra tag (or in body tag), seams the best idea.